# Can't connect to my own public server(Port forwarding) but Port Checker Tools can

Tags: python, sockets, networking, portforwarding

- I run my server from my computer using Python Socket.
- I also Port forwarded(TCP/UDP) the port I'm using to make it public for everyone.
- I tested my server with Port Checker Tools(ex. https://www.canyouseeme.org/) from a different external address(different Wi-Fi) and it worked!

And now I am trying to connect to the server from Python using the following script I found online:

```
import socket
import time


ip = "my IP"
port = (the port im using, 5 digits, int)
retry = 5
delay = 10
timeout = 3

def isOpen(ip, port):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(timeout)
        try:
                s.connect((ip, int(port)))
                s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                return True
        except:
                return False
        finally:
                s.close()

def checkHost(ip, port):
        ipup = False
        for i in range(retry):
                if isOpen(ip, port):
                        ipup = True
                        break
                else:
                        time.sleep(delay)
        return ipup

if checkHost(ip, port):
        print( ip + " is UP")
```

This script doesn't work! And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. So can anybody help me connect to my server like the Port Checker Tools does? Thanks.

Comment: Are the server and client inside the __same__ network behind a NAT router but you try to access the server using the public IP address? In this case your router might simply not support [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Oh! Thanks for letting me know this. Is it possible to make my router support the NAT loopback? If so, how? thanks.

Comment: *"Is it possible to make my router support the NAT loopback?"* - No. It either can do it or it can't.

Comment: Some network details would probably go a long way toward helping us help you.  What IP addresses and ports are involved - for the two computers, the router's internal IP and the router's external (?) IP?  Are you on a residential ISP's router?  Are you on a corporate network?  Are the two computers on the same subnet?

Comment: If the client and server are on the SAME network, use the server's *LAN IP* to connect.  If the client and server are on DIFFERENT networks, use the NAT router's *PUBLIC IP* to connect (and of course, enable port forwarding from the NAT router IP/port to the server LAN IP/port).